# Subshell Command Execution

Tags: bash

I'm reading the bash manual and came to a section that states:

"Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment"

My question is, is there a way I could actually see what was executed in the subshell.  For example say I wrote the line below.  What would I need to do to actually see what was executed in the subshell?

```
$ printf "first\nsecond\nthird" | grep -E "(first|second)"
```

How would I check what was actually executed in the subshell (i suspect it does a grep for "first" and then a second shell to grep for "second", but I'd just like to see what it's doing).

Comment: You don't have "commands grouped with parentheses" (or grouped at all). You have a pipeline containing two parts; the second part `grep -E "(first|second)"` is ONE COMMAND with an ARGUMENT that CONTAINS parentheses (quoted) as DATA, which `grep -E` treats as an extended-regex operator, and it is run as one process; since it's not a builtin, it doesn't run in any kind of shell, main or sub-. The next sentence of 3.7.3, which you omitted, notes that builtin commands in a pipeline are executed in a subshell -- though that's no longer entirely true, see `lastpipe` in 3.2.3 and 4.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

First I am not sure `grep` exec is in two subshells.

But to check what happen when you exec the command you can use command `truss`. Something like:

```
printf "first\nsecond\nthird" | truss -o out.log grep -E "(first|second)"
```

will store in `out.log` the system calls, the signals, etc command do.

Here is the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/truss/) of `truss` for future reference.

About `strace` I think you can replace it in the command:

```
printf "first\nsecond\nthird" | strace -o out.log grep -E "(first|second)"
```

but be aware the output will differ, compared to `truss`

If you want to trace the entire shell, subshell creation, syscalls, etc you should use command in format:

```
strace -o out.log 'printf "first\nsecond\nthird" | grep -E "(first|second)"'
```

Comment: What's truss? I don't think that's a package in Arch Linux because it's throwing an error when I use it.  Online it looks like it's similar to s-trace.  Do you know if it's the same command to check it using strace?

Comment: @johnsmith, check my edited answer

Comment: Here, `truss` or `strace` would run within the subshell the shell starts for the right-hand side of the pipeline. So they won't show the system calls involved in the subshell creation. You'd need to run `strace bash -c 'foo | bar'` or so

Comment: @ilkkachu, my understanding is OP want to see what happen in subshell so this is the reason i construct the command on this way. If OP want the entire shells, subshells, etc your idea will work. Will add it in to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can see it directly.

`xtrace` (`set -x`) does show nesting level for `eval`s and command substitutions, but not for groups in parenthesis.

Bash runs subshells in child processes, so in principle you *could* try to run `strace` or similar to see the `fork()` (`clone()` on Linux) and `execve()` system calls the shell and it's children make, but the output is a bit hard interpret. Also, builtins like that `printf` there don't show up in `execve()` calls, and when a Bash process only has one command to run, it skips one level of forks. E.g. `bash -c '/bin/false'` doesn't fork for the external command, and similarly `(/bin/false)` only has one fork for the subshell, not two for subshell and external command.

You could also print `$BASHPID` in various places it compare it to `$$`. `$BASHPID` contains the PID of the Bash process actually running at the time while `$$` contains the PID of the main Bash process and doesn't update for subshells. Though it doesn't show you the commands that are run, and sprinkling those printouts is a bit messy:

```
$ echo $$ >&2; { echo "lhs: $BASHPID" >&2; printf foobar; } | { echo "rhs: $BASHPID" >&2; grep oo; }
30163
rhs: 30166
lhs: 30165
foobar
```

Yes, we can tell from the output that both parts of a pipeline run in subshells, even though that wasn't mentioned in the part you quoted.

Anyway, what runs in subshells is mostly those, the three your quote mentiones, plus pipelines.

Async/background processes are obvious: they run at the same time as the shell, so they can't be in the same process. The parts of a pipeline also have to run concurrently, so at most one can run in the main shell process. (In Bash, the rightmost part will do that if the `lastpipe` option is set and effective, otherwise they all get their own subshells/processes.)

Parenthesized groups explicitly ask for a subshell, and well, I can't think of an excuse for command substitutions, so I guess we'll just have to accept they also do.

Changes in a subshell don't propagate up to the main shell, so it's also relatively simple to test this. E.g. if you run:

```
bash -c 's=
         s+=direct.
         (s+=parens.)
         $(s+=comsub.)
         s+=pipeleft. | s+=piperight.
         s+=async. &
         eval s+=eval.
         echo $s'
```

You get the output `direct.eval.`, so those are the parts that *didn't* run in subshells. The rest did. If you add `-O lastpipe` before the `-c`, or `shopt -s lastpipe;` within the script, you'll also see `piperight` added to the list.